# Getting WebApi Exception Response in an Exception Filter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

We installed an Exception filter

```
public class APIErrorHandlerAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
     // Sets up log4net logger
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
        (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is BusinessException)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message),
                ReasonPhrase = "Exception"
            });

        }

        //Log Critical errors
        log.Info("/****************** API Begin Error ******************/");
        log.Info("Exception:" + context.Exception + "  Case:" + CaseHelper.GetCurrentCaseID() + "  UserID:" + UserHelper.GetCurrentUserID());
        log.Info("/****************** API End Error ******************/");

        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Message: {0}\nStack Trace: {1}", context.Exception.Message, context.Exception.StackTrace)),
            ReasonPhrase = "Critical Exception",
        });
    }
}
```

for all WebApi routes

```
    //*** Log API Error Globally using Log4net
    public static void RegisterFilters(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiError", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Filters.Add(new LRAPIErrorHandlerAttribute());
    }
```

We also have an authorization attribute that we attach to some controllers. It looks something like this:

```
public class LegalRadiusAPIAuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IFilter
{
    public string Permissions { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public string Users { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NonAuthoritativeInformation); //203
        }
     }
}
```

So, if an unauthenticated user hits a route that requires him to be logged in, we throw. If I debug inside this filter and open up the exception dialog I can see the following properties on the exception object:

[image]

If I look at the `Response` prop I see all the pertinent details of the exception thrown.

The problem is when this exception gets handled by `APIErrorHandlerAttribute`. By the time the exception gets to the handler I can't seem to find the `Response` property of the exception in `context.Exception`...

[image]

Even though, at the handler I get the following error message from the caught exception:

> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

implying that the exception in context should have that property.

I feel like I'm having scope issues and that the original exception object that was thrown in the filter isn't in the `context` parameter of the Exception Handler.

Comment: And if you click on the `plus` icon on the `[System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException]` ?

Comment: @Hackerman That's it! Now, how do I access `[System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException]` from `context.Exception`?

Comment: Just right click on it and add another watch. That is going to give you the appropiate casting in order to retrieve the info from the context :)

Comment: That did it @Hackerman! Write it up as an Answer so I can mark it as accepted :D

Comment: Consider it done...tomorrow at first hour :)

Comment: Aaaand, done!....happy weekend everyone!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to access the `[System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException]` from your `context.Exception`. In order to do that, and based on the picture, you need to `right click` on the `[System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException]` and add a `watcher` on it. That is going to give you the appropriate `casting` in order to retrieve the information from the `context`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 `var exceptionData = new ExceptionData
                    {
                        Name = "exception name",
                        Message = "exception message"
                    };
       Content = new ObjectContent<ExceptionData>(exceptionData, JsonFormatter),`